# Inconsistent behavior using IDataReader.Read()

Tags: c#, idatareader

I'm running into an issue that is mind boggling to me. I've noticed that IDataReader.Read() is acting differently depending on how the IDbCommand.CommandText is set.

In the code below - If 'AID' is set and passed to EntAgencyId(), reader.Read() returns true and the program is able to enter into the while loop. If I just set 'query' in EntAgencyId() using the same value I'm passing to the function ('455'), the program is never able to enter the while loop (the same behavior happens when passing in 'AID' from a textbox.text).

```
public string EntAgencyId(string AID)
{
    cmd = uasConnection.CreateCommand();
    //query = "select * from EnterpriseAgencyTbl where AOCId = " + AID; //<--Works
    query = "select * from EnterpriseAgencyTbl where AOCId = 455";  //<--Causes issue

    cmd.CommandText = query;
    reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

    while (reader.Read())
    {
        EntAgId = reader["Id"].ToString();
        AgencyName = reader["Name"].ToString();
    }

    reader.Close();
    return AgencyName;
}
```

When debugging, 'query' always has the same value, so why is this making a difference with .Read().

Food for thought - .Read() returns true if there are more rows; otherwise, false. In this case I tried just reading the first single row using the Item property and GetValue(), both result in an 'Object not set to an instance of an object' error.

I've completely run out of ideas, so any help will be appreciated!

Comment: I *strongly* suspect your diagnostics are incorrect. One the query string has been constructed, nothing's going to care *how* it was constructed. (And you shouldn't be constructing the query using a textbox value as part of the SQL, of course. Use parameterized SQL instead.)

Comment: Could you add the code that calls `EntAgencyId`?

Comment: Out of curiosity, what's the type of the AOCId column?  And are you passing the string "'455'" (with tick quotes) into the function?  or "455"?

Comment: It seems the issue stemmed from the code calling EntAgencyId. I apologize for not looking deeper before posting. Thanks for everyone's advice. I have fixed the issue and I'm making changes to mirror some of your suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

If `AID` may come from an untrusted source, then you should *really* be using parameters.

Use the following code instead:

```
query = "select * from EnterpriseAgencyTbl where AOCId = @AOCId";

cmd.CommandText = query;
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@AOCId", SqlDbType.Int) { Value = int.Parse(AID) });
```

Then see if this behaves the same using static inputs, such as:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@AOCId", SqlDbType.Int) { Value = 455 });
```

Note: I'm making the assumption, based on 'Id' in the name, that AOCId is an int type.